# Angularjs : How to prevent ng-change triggered after loading the page when ng-change connected to a datepicker input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have some issue here about datepicker input with a directive of ng-change. seems like a change is triggered when the page is loaded because the datepicker is inside js document ready function. how can i prevent that if possible? thanks

index.html :

```
<input 
    id="birthDate"
    style="width:250px;"
    class="form-control" 
    type="text" 
    ng-model="data.birth_date"
    ng-change="postHelloWorld()"
         />


$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#birthDate').datepicker({
            format : 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });
    })
```

controller :

```
 $scope.postHelloWorld = function() {

            alert('hello World!');

}
```

Issue here is the alert always showing after the loading of the page.

Comment: remove `$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#birthDate').datepicker({
            format : 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });
    })`

Comment: what if i want  ng-change directive on my datepicker input? for example i want to calculate the year for date of birth every changes?

Comment: remove `ng-model="data.birth_date"` from element input.

Comment: it will be there I think because of your `document.ready` it is calling initially

Answer (score 0):

Here I update your code. And its working for me. Please check where you went wrong.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

<body ng-controller="sampleCtrl">

<input 
    id="birthDate"
    style="width:250px;"
    class="form-control" 
    type="text" 
    ng-model="data.birth_date"
    ng-change="postHelloWorld()" /> 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#birthDate').datepicker({
            format : 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });
    })

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.postHelloWorld = function(){
        alert("Hello World " + $scope.data.birth_date);
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```